# $.Post asp.net method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, post

It must be a classic problem, but I couldn't find any answer to my problem on line. 
the page is located at

```
https://localhost/Secured/Report/FileWriterManager.aspx
```

Here is my Jquery code.

```
    par = 'some data';
    $.post(
            '/Secured/Report/FileWriterManager.aspx/CallAjax',
            { strPar: par },
             function (msg) {
                 $('#lblError').text('Value Returned: ' + msg);
             }
        );
```

The code behind is Like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string CallAjax(string strPar)
{

    return 'OK';

}
```

when i debug with firefox, the post statement goes through line per line, execute the lblError filling. the response is the whole FileWriterManager.aspx html code.What am i doing wrong? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I think you should use `PageMethods.CallAjax(par)` in your javascript code...

Comment: I have tried pagemethod, and it was calling my method, but  the problem with PageMethods is I can't access any controls in the form.

Comment: What do you mean? The method will return a string that you can put into a control. `var s = PageMethods.CallAjax(par); $('#lblError').text('Result: ' + s);`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No on code behind CallAjax I need to get some information from the form.

Comment: I think this is a totally different issue now.

Comment: I agree with the comment from @Vlad. Notice that the `[WebMethod]` is static (a requirement for ASP.NET WebForms page methods). Therefor, it cannot access any controls on the page, since the method is simply not participating in the page life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Buffer="true"` to the `<%# Page` directive on the FileWriterManager.aspx page, and then in this function call the code `Response.Clear()` to clear the generated HTML response.  Then use `Response.Write` to generate the result to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it even does not call my method to start with, so adding Response clear would not change my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the normal page response when trying to call a `[WebMethod]`, you should first check that ASP.NET Ajax is configured correctly. Specifically, check the `<HttpModules>` section in web.config.

For an ASP.NET 3.5 application, using the built-in web server in Visual Studio:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

When using IIS:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </modules>
</system.web>
```

The reason for this, is that the ScriptModule actually 'intercepts' request like /WebForm.aspx/WebMethod and handles the calling of the static method and the return of the response. So if that's not happening, chances are the module is not configured.

If you've done the configuration, then add an `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>` to the page, and enable page methods. Then test if you can call the page methods using Firebug: `PageMethods.CallAjax("foo")`.